# PHP SoapFault not WSDL Schema compliant in soapUI?

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, soapui

I came across a strange one today, it goes like this:

I'm setting up test suites for QAing a web service of mine, which is
written in PHP5 - making use of the class [SoapFault](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapfault.php) among others.

I use the class to return error message to the clients. Example:

```
if (!$this->CheckHost(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')))
{
    return new SoapFault(S_CLIENT, S_STRING_IP, "", S_DETAIL_IP);
}
```

Returning a SoapFault if the client is not authorized...

Now, if I add an Schema Compliance assertion in [soapUI 3.0.1](http://www.soapui.org/) it tells 
me that the returned message is not compliant to it's wsdl file.

The WSDL-file is written by me and does in deed not contain a description 
of the actual SoapFault class. Would that be needed? Thought not because
SoapFault is spezified in Soap 1.1 anyways.

The actual response looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>ERR_102</faultstring>
         <faultactor/>
         <detail>IP error message</detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The soapUI error message is:

> Element 'detail' with element-only
>   content type cannot have text content.

Does anyone have a hint what I'm doing wrong?

tia

K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soap 1.1 xml schema (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/) defines the detail element as

```
   <xs:complexType name="detail"><xs:sequence> 
      <xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" /> 
    </xs:sequence> 
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="lax" /> 
  </xs:complexType>
```

meaning that it can not contain just text as in your fault. Try changing the response to something like

```
...
   <detail><msg>IP error message</msg></detail>
...
```

Hope this helps!

regards,

/Ole
eviware.com

Comment: Thx for your reply, I gave it a shot and found that for some reason "<msg>".S_SOAP_FAULT_DETAIL_INVALID_TICKET."</msg>" get's escaped to html ltMSGgt ... and soapUI gets me an error stating "Unecpected CDATA". Any ideas how to pass that error detail? TIA